# Problem to list blobs with Azure Data Lake gen2

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake

I've used Azure Storage(Blobs) to store files.

Now I'm planning to migrate to Data Lake Gen2. Unfortunately, after I've switched connection string to gen2 storage it shows 400 Error with Bad Request to me on ListBlob() method.

Code example:

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
var myClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = myClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
var dirRef= container.GetDirectoryReference(directory);
var blobs = dirRef.ListBlobs();
```

So, when I'm trying to iterate blobs it generates an exception. Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known issue, see [Known issues with Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-known-issues).

> Blob Storage APIs and Azure Data Lake Gen2 APIs aren't interoperable with each other.
>
> Blob storage APIs aren't yet available to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 accounts.
>
> These APIs are disabled to prevent inadvertent data access issues that could arise because Blob Storage APIs aren't yet interoperable with Azure Data Lake Gen2 APIs.

Comment: Is there any way to get access through .NET SDK? to DFS endpoint?

Comment: @Estatic Seems there is no sdk for gen2, you could try the [Azure Data Lake Store REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/data-lake-storage-gen2).

Comment: seems I'm going to do that

Comment: This new library seems to work nicely now. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-data-movement-library